# POST a form with Jquery AJAX When input is a File

Tags: jquery, post

I have several areas where I use AJAX to submit text fields.

```
 var name = $("input#name").val(); 

   $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "bin/process.php",  
      data: "&name=" + name,  
      success: function() {  
       //handle response here
     }  
    });
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this if the input type is a file? Doing

`var name = $("input#file").val();`      doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, jQuery cannot POST a form via AJAX if it contains a upload field.

You can try this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done using an iFrame to send the file to the server.

The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is a great resource for that.

Here is another [upload script](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) which uses xhr when possible (FF, Safari) and falls back gracefully to iFrame if necessary (IE)