# Call to a member function move() on a non-object Laravel 4 file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I keep hitting `internal service 500` error and the reason is `Call to a member function move() on a non-object` when trying to access the `Input::file('uploadname');` method.

If I do a var dump using the following code:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(Input::all());
echo '</pre>';
```

I get the output that there is data in the field, but when accessing the `Input::hasFile('uploadname');` it gives false?

Here is the form code:

```
<div id="div123">
                    <input type="button" value="Upload CV" class="uploadCV">
                </div>
                <div id="uploadbutton">
                    <input type="file" name="upload_cv_company_rep" class="cv" id="upload_cv_company_rep"/>
                </div>
```

The button is displayed, when you click it, it triggers the `input type="file"` stuff.

It shows the following `var_dump` in the console:

[image: console output from var_dump]

and the code in my controller is:

```
public function uploadUser() {

    if(Input::hasFile('upload_cv_company_rep')) {
        Input::file('upload_cv_company_rep')->move('uploads/');
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(Input::all());
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}
```

here is the ajax part:

```
$("#upload_employee_form").submit(function(e){
//    e.preventDefault();
//    alert("hey");

var d = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_employee_form'));
d.append('password', $('.password').val());
d.append('referencecode', $('.ref_code').val());
console.log(d);
$.ajax({
    url: '/laravel/rsms/public/company-representative-create-user',
    data: d,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
});

return false;
});
```

Comment: "By default, jQuery cannot POST a form via AJAX if it contains a upload field." + suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597487/post-a-form-with-jquery-ajax-when-input-is-a-file

Comment: @Unnawut I am using FormData, which seems to work for a lot of people. But in my case I am struggling.

Comment: Ah right, my bad not knowing about FormData.

Comment: The strange thing is, it's working for me with small file sizes, but not with large ones. Of course I've increased server post and filesize settings, but no change. Maybe FormData has some size limit?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not it should be done:

```
var d = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_employee_form'));
d.append('password', $('.password').val());
d.append('referencecode', $('.ref_code').val());
```

^ You're doing it wrong. First of all there's no point using native DOM selector when jquery is included. Second, what if you add more fields later? You would have to `d.append(...)` that fields.

The right and very common approach sending serialized form including files:

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            // Note, both processData and contentType should be set to false
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,

            url     : "/laravel/rsms/public/company-representative-create-user",
            data    : data,
            success : function(response) {
                  alert(response);
            }
        });

});
```

And you no longer need `d.append()` even in case you add some fields in future. The form serialization is totally dynamical.

As for the server side, keep doing what you do, that should work now